# Strange Behaviour of Rich Text Editor with Umbraco

Tags: jquery, umbraco7, archetypes

I am using `Umbraco 7.1` and `Archetype 1.4.1 Beta`,

Now what is my actual problem is when I am creating the new DataType that can allow to use Multiple Controls With + Sign (`i.e, Textstring and RichTextbox Editor`).

When I am trying to use Rich Text Editor inside the Archetype using Customer Control which contains RTE (RichTextbox Editor and Textstring) it throws error whenever I am Clicking Save and Publish.

My issue in the Below Image

[image]

And the Jquery Giving me erros in console is

[image]

Anyone one can help me in this!. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for RTE to use into the `7.1.0 Version` of the `Umbraco` for that they have Resolved the issues with the `Umbraco 7.1.3 and 7.1.2`.

I have asked the Question on Below Link and Found the Solution for using multiple RTE with Single Control.

[Reference](https://github.com/imulus/Archetype/issues/33#issuecomment-39017250)